# NSTableView Reusing Rows with Old Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I've created a table view as part of an app for my school which allows students to enter in their homework and then check it off and have it disappear, much like the reminders app. The issue I'm running into is that when I check off a row to make it disappear, I delete that row from the table and the `HomeworkItem` with its data from the array which holds all the `HomeworkItem`s; however, the next time I try to add a row (by clicking on the buffer row at the end), the new row added is the same row I just deleted, with the same `HomeworkItem` information, even though that `HomeworkItem` has been deleted from the array. I remember reading that NSableViews try to reuse rows to be efficient with memory, but I don't understand why the row is hanging onto the old information. Could someone explain why this might be happening or how I can fix it?

here's my code for the custom TableViewCell:

HomeworkTableViewCell.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ClassViewController.h"

@class ClassViewController;
@class AppDelegate;

@interface HomeworkTableCellView : NSTableCellView

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *assignmentName;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSDatePicker *dueDatePicker;
@property BOOL isCompleted;
@property NSInteger rowNumber;
@property (weak) AppDelegate *ad;
@property NSTableView *superTable;
@property ClassViewController *superCVC;

- (void)setSuperRow:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)completed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)dateChanged:(id)sender;

@end
```

HomeworkTableViewCell.m:

```
#import "HomeworkTableCellView.h"

@implementation HomeworkTableCellView

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
//    NSLog(@"I");//TEST
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.ad = [[NSApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        self.superTable = self.ad.classViewController.homeworkTable;
        self.superCVC = self.ad.classViewController;
        self.isCompleted = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSuperRow:(id)sender{
    [self.superCVC updateRow:sender];
}
- (IBAction)completed:(id)sender{
    self.isCompleted = !self.isCompleted;
    [self.superCVC changeStateOfHomeworkItem:self];
    [self.superCVC updateRow:sender];
}
- (IBAction)dateChanged:(id)sender{
    [self.superCVC updateRow:sender];
    [self.superCVC editDateOfHomeworkItem];
}
@end
```

And here is a link to a video of the problem occurring: http://youtu.be/Ot8w5oz8L-E

The text in the console is a representation of what is in the homework array after deleting an object, so it's clear the deleted object isn't there anymore.

EDIT:
Here's what I came up with using uasi's suggestion:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    HomeworkTableCellView *HTCV = [self.homeworkTable makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];//maybe owner:nil
    [HTCV.assignmentName setStringValue: @""];
    [HTCV.dueDatePicker setDateValue: [[NSDate alloc]initWithString:@"1-1-1 0:0:0 +0000"]];//false date for testing
    HTCV.isCompleted = NO;
    [HTCV.checkBox setState:NSOffState];

    [self updateTableView];

    return HTCV;
}

- (void)updateTableView{
    for (int i = 0; i < self.ad.currentSubject.homework.count; i++) {
        HomeworkTableCellView *HTCV = [self.homeworkTable viewAtColumn:0 row:i makeIfNecessary:NO];
        HomeworkItem *HI = [self.ad.currentSubject.homework objectAtIndex:i];
        [HTCV.dueDatePicker setDateValue: HI.dueDate];
        [HTCV.assignmentName setStringValue: HI.details];
    }
}
```

Comment: The video seems to be private :/

Comment: Note that tableView:viewForTableColumn:row: is part of NSTableViewDelegate, not NSTableViewDataSource. So make sure whatever object implements that method is the delegate (and data source) of the table view.

Comment: Good call, thank you. Completely missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might not use `-tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` to make table cell views. While the document claims "this method is mandatory", a comment on the method found in `<AppKit/NSTableView.h>` says 'this method is required for the "Cell Based" TableView, and *is optional for the "View Based" TableView*.'

Instead you can use `NSTableViewDelegate`'s `-tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` method:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
   viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                  row:(NSInteger)row
{
  // Instantiate a view object from XIB or reuse one in the cache.
  NSString *identifier = @"YOUR_CELL_VIEW_IDENTIFIER";
  HomeworkTableCellView *HTCV = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:identifier owner:nil];

#if 0
  // If you have not put a HomeworkTableCellView object in a XIB with identifier,
  // you'll need to create an instance programatically like this;
  // It seems not to be the case, though.
  if (HTCV == nil) {
    HTCV = [[HomeworkTableCellView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    HTCV.identifier = identifier;
  }
#endif

  // Do initialization anything specific to a row here,
  // because the view's -init{WithCoder:,WithFrame:} method
  // is not always called for each row due to the cache mechanism.
  HomeworkItem *HI = [self.homeworkArray objectAtIndex:row];
  [HTCV.dueDatePicker setDateValue: HI.dueDate];
  // ...

  return HTCV;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll try this. What is the view I'm returning at the end, though? would it just be the HTCV, or do I need to create something different? (I'm pretty new to this, and not 100% solid on all the different views yet)

Comment: Sorry, that `view` was a typo. Fixed the answer.

Comment: For some reason, `-tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` isn't working for me. It's not even being called. It is a view based table so I'm not sure why. I've updated my original post with what I tried to do for that method.

Comment: I fixed this by setting the delegate for the tableview (sorry for the dumb mistake), but now it's not displaying any rows at all

Comment: After much tweaking and failure to understand how this method works, I finally got it working. I was under the assumption that this would be called for every row when something was updated, but apparently it's only called for new rows. What i did was use this as an initialization as you suggested, and then have it call an update method which loops through the entire table and updates each row with the info it needs. I'll post that code in my original post. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old but, I'm just putting it out there for people like, myself that were looking for a solution.

```
if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(usesStaticContents)])
  //Method currenly only available on OS X 10.10 or later
  {
    //This is used to prevent table view rows from being reused
    /*From:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/
      Normally, a table view will only keep around a subset of the total number of rows potentially available (in general, this is limited to the visible region, plus some overdrawn allowance for responsive scrolling). A static table view keeps all views added to the table around when usesStaticContents=YES
      */
      //Also check out: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/TableViewOverview/TableViewOverview.html

     self.tableView.usesStaticContents = YES;

   }
```

**Note: Your app may exhibit higher memory utilization by using this solution (for obvious reasons). However, in my testing it wasn't a big difference, your mileage may vary.**